# WSO2 API Manager(2.1.0) solr issue: undefined field

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2

In WSO2 APIM-2.1.0 I'm facing solrException as: `ERROR {org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore} -  org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: undefined field c/o`
Due to above issue, **unable to view API listing & Application Listing in `/store` url.**

I will give background of why above issue is happening:
(For all below steps I've referred this [documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/apidocs/store/index.html).
1. I've created couple of applications (around 1000) using [Create New Application](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/apidocs/store/index.html#!/operations#ApplicationIndividual#applicationsPost).
2. Generated the keys for newly created application using [Generate Keys for Application](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/apidocs/store/index.html#!/operations#ApplicationIndividual#applicationsGenerateKeysPost).
3. Subscribed these application to the existing APIs using [Subscription](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/apidocs/store/index.html#!/operations#SubscriptionMultitple#subscriptionsMultiplePost).

Performed above steps for 1000 applications, I'm able to regenerate tokens, get details of it & make an API calls using keys. This all is happening without errors using API (not from UI).

After that I realized that WSO2-APIM-1.9.0 was throwing an error for creating applications with special characters like `'/', ','`. Because in exception it mentioned that **undefined field c/o**, I've added c/o in many application names as **XYZ Inc c/o**.

Next debug step I've performed is to remove `/` from all application names wherever exist, so updated `AM_APPLICATION` table.
Also updated same thing in `UM_HYBRID_ROLE` table. 
But somehow I'm unable to see these entries in `UM_ROLE_PERMISSION` table.
After performing I'm seeing the error as `org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: undefined field co`. This made me realize that error is associated with `UM_ROLE_PERMISSION`.

What will be my next step to solve this issue ?

Here is the complete stack trace I'm getting as soon as logged in to `/store`:

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2018-03-02 12:21:00,189]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.permission.update.PermissionUpdater} -  Permission cache updated for tenant -1234 {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.permission.update.PermissionUpdater}
TID: [-1234] [] [2018-03-02 12:21:00,532]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil} -  'admin@carbon.super [-1234]' logged in at [2018-03-02 12:21:00,531-0600] {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil}
TID: [-1234] [] [2018-03-02 12:21:06,575] ERROR {org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore} -  org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: undefined field co
        at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema.getDynamicFieldType(IndexSchema.java:1298)
        at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema$SolrQueryAnalyzer.getWrappedAnalyzer(IndexSchema.java:444)
        at org.apache.lucene.analysis.DelegatingAnalyzerWrapper$DelegatingReuseStrategy.getReusableComponents(DelegatingAnalyzerWrapper.java:74)
        at org.apache.lucene.analysis.Analyzer.tokenStream(Analyzer.java:172)
        at org.apache.lucene.util.QueryBuilder.createFieldQuery(QueryBuilder.java:199)
        at org.apache.solr.parser.SolrQueryParserBase.newFieldQuery(SolrQueryParserBase.java:370)
        at org.apache.solr.parser.SolrQueryParserBase.getFieldQuery(SolrQueryParserBase.java:753)
        at org.apache.solr.parser.SolrQueryParserBase.handleBareTokenQuery(SolrQueryParserBase.java:537)
        at org.apache.solr.parser.QueryParser.Term(QueryParser.java:299)
        at org.apache.solr.parser.QueryParser.Clause(QueryParser.java:185)
        at org.apache.solr.parser.QueryParser.Query(QueryParser.java:139)
        at org.apache.solr.parser.QueryParser.Clause(QueryParser.java:189)
        at org.apache.solr.parser.QueryParser.Query(QueryParser.java:107)
        at org.apache.solr.parser.QueryParser.TopLevelQuery(QueryParser.java:96)
        at org.apache.solr.parser.SolrQueryParserBase.parse(SolrQueryParserBase.java:151)
        at org.apache.solr.search.LuceneQParser.parse(LuceneQParser.java:50)
        at org.apache.solr.search.QParser.getQuery(QParser.java:141)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.component.QueryComponent.prepare(QueryComponent.java:203)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler.handleRequestBody(SearchHandler.java:229)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:143)
        at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:2064)
        at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.embedded.EmbeddedSolrServer.request(EmbeddedSolrServer.java:179)
        at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrRequest.process(SolrRequest.java:135)
        at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient.query(SolrClient.java:943)
        at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient.query(SolrClient.java:958)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.indexing.solr.SolrClient.query(SolrClient.java:613)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.indexing.solr.SolrClient.query(SolrClient.java:528)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.indexing.service.ContentBasedSearchService.searchContentInternal(ContentBasedSearchService.java:166)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.indexing.service.ContentBasedSearchService.searchByAttribute(ContentBasedSearchService.java:279)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.indexing.internal.IndexingServiceComponent$AttributeSearchServiceImpl.search(IndexingServiceComponent.java:162)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.indexing.internal.IndexingServiceComponent$AttributeSearchServiceImpl.search(IndexingServiceComponent.java:175)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.indexing.internal.IndexingServiceComponent$AttributeSearchServiceImpl.search(IndexingServiceComponent.java:189)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.indexing.internal.IndexingServiceComponent$AttributeSearchServiceImpl.search(IndexingServiceComponent.java:156)
        at org.wso2.carbon.governance.api.util.GovernanceUtils.performAttributeSearch(GovernanceUtils.java:2118)
        at org.wso2.carbon.governance.api.util.GovernanceUtils.findGovernanceArtifacts(GovernanceUtils.java:2016)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIConsumerImpl.getAllPaginatedAPIsByStatus(APIConsumerImpl.java:573)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.UserAwareAPIConsumer.getAllPaginatedAPIsByStatus(UserAwareAPIConsumer.java:36)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.hostobjects.APIStoreHostObject.getPaginatedAPIsByStatus(APIStoreHostObject.java:1739)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.hostobjects.APIStoreHostObject.jsFunction_getAllPaginatedAPIs(APIStoreHostObject.java:1669)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:126)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.FunctionObject.call(FunctionObject.java:386)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callN(OptRuntime.java:52)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.modules.api.c1._c_anonymous_5(/store/modules/api/api.jag:136)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.modules.api.c1.call(/store/modules/api/api.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.applyOrCall(ScriptRuntime.java:2430)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.BaseFunction.execIdCall(BaseFunction.java:269)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.IdFunctionObject.call(IdFunctionObject.java:97)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call2(OptRuntime.java:42)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.modules.api.c0._c_anonymous_16(/store/modules/api/module.jag:54)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.modules.api.c0.call(/store/modules/api/module.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callN(OptRuntime.java:52)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.site.blocks.api.api_listing_all.c0._c_anonymous_3(/store/site/blocks/api/api-listing-all/block.jag:74)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.site.blocks.api.api_listing_all.c0.call(/store/site/blocks/api/api-listing-all/block.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:32)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.jagg.c0._c_anonymous_26(/store/jagg/jagg.jag:232)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.jagg.c0.call(/store/jagg/jagg.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callName(OptRuntime.java:63)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.jagg.c0._c_anonymous_51(/store/jagg/jagg.jag:682)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.jagg.c0.call(/store/jagg/jagg.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:32)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.site.themes.wso_2.templates.api.listing.c0._c_anonymous_1(/store/site/themes/wso2/templates/api/listing/template.jag:16)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.site.themes.wso_2.templates.api.listing.c0.call(/store/site/themes/wso2/templates/api/listing/template.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callN(OptRuntime.java:52)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.jagg.c0._c_anonymous_26(/store/jagg/jagg.jag:243)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.jagg.c0.call(/store/jagg/jagg.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callName(OptRuntime.java:63)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.jagg.c0._c_anonymous_52(/store/jagg/jagg.jag:698)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.jagg.c0.call(/store/jagg/jagg.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:32)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.site.themes.wso_2.templates.layout.base.c0._c_anonymous_1(/store/site/themes/wso2/templates/layout/base/template.jag:42)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.site.themes.wso_2.templates.layout.base.c0.call(/store/site/themes/wso2/templates/layout/base/template.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callN(OptRuntime.java:52)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.jagg.c0._c_anonymous_26(/store/jagg/jagg.jag:243)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.jagg.c0.call(/store/jagg/jagg.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callName(OptRuntime.java:63)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.jagg.c0._c_anonymous_52(/store/jagg/jagg.jag:695)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.jagg.c0.call(/store/jagg/jagg.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:32)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.site.themes.wso_2.templates.page.base.c0._c_anonymous_1(/store/site/themes/wso2/templates/page/base/template.jag:70)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.site.themes.wso_2.templates.page.base.c0.call(/store/site/themes/wso2/templates/page/base/template.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callN(OptRuntime.java:52)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.jagg.c0._c_anonymous_50(/store/jagg/jagg.jag:678)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.jagg.c0.call(/store/jagg/jagg.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:32)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.site.pages.c0._c_anonymous_1(/store/site/pages/list-apis.jag:24)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.site.pages.c0.call(/store/site/pages/list-apis.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call0(OptRuntime.java:23)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.site.pages.c0._c_script_0(/store/site/pages/list-apis.jag:10)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.site.pages.c0.call(/store/site/pages/list-apis.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:394)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3091)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.site.pages.c0.call(/store/site/pages/list-apis.jag)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.site.pages.c0.exec(/store/site/pages/list-apis.jag)
        at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.execScript(RhinoEngine.java:567)
        at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.exec(RhinoEngine.java:273)
        at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.exec(WebAppManager.java:588)
        at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.execute(WebAppManager.java:508)
        at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryServlet.doGet(JaggeryServlet.java:24)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:747)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:485)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:377)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:337)
        at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryFilter.doFilter(JaggeryFilter.java:21)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.wso2.carbon.ui.filters.cache.ContentTypeBasedCachePreventionFilter.doFilter(ContentTypeBasedCachePreventionFilter.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:120)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
        at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:57)
        at org.wso2.carbon.event.receiver.core.internal.tenantmgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:48)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:159)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:958)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:452)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1087)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1756)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1715)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
 {org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution to above problem. The issue was coming because WSO2-APIM unable to generate correct `solr` query, when `Application Name` contains `:` character.
I removed `:` from table `AM_APPLICATION` (column Name: `NAME`) & from table `UM_HYBRID_ROLE` (column name: `UM_ROLE_NAME`).
Then I've performed following steps:

1. stopped the `WSO2-APIM`
2. deleted `solr` directory
3. Rename the `<lastAccessTimeLocation>` element in the `<APIM_2.0.0_HOME>/repository/conf/registry.xml` file. If you use a clustered/distributed API Manager setup, change the file in the API Publisher node.
   For example, change the
   `/_system/local/repository/components/org.wso2.carbon.registry/indexing/lastaccesstime` registry path to
   `/_system/local/repository/components/org.wso2.carbon.registry/indexing/lastaccesstime_1`.

This has solved my problem. But now I ran into another [performance issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49150542/wso2-apim-taking-long-time-for-retrieving-applications-list).