# WSO2 APIM: Taking long time for retrieving applications list

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2

I'm using `WSO2-APIM-2.1.0`. Which internally uses `solr 5.2.1`.
Inside `WSO2-APIM-2.1.0`, I've added around `2087` applications. Wso2 internally generating the solr `OR` query which has around `2087 OR clauses` of `121825` characters.

When I tried to get application list though the API call:
`curl -k -H "Authorization: Bearer access_token" "https://localhost:9443/api/am/publisher/v0.11/subscriptions?apiId=apiId&limit=2200"`
(It took around 6 minutes, which is too long.)

Using the link https://localhost:9443/store (by clicking on applications),  it's not loading application list.(as browser is timing out)

I was getting exception of `maxBooleanClauses`. Then I made following changes:
I've modified the file `repository/conf/solr/registry-indexing/conf/solrconfig.xml` and modified the property: `<maxBooleanClauses>16000</maxBooleanClauses>`.

How can I speed-up the response ?